# How many ROS paths can ~/.bashrc file store? Will the path influence each other

Tags: ros, path

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I met a strange problem.
This is the path in my bashrc

---

```
#source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash
#export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH:/home/chaoqun/catkin_test/src/ORB_SLAM
#source /home/chaoqun/active_exploring/devel/setup.bash
#source /home/chaoqun/catkin_test/devel/setup.bash
#source /home/chaoqun/active_exploring/devel/setup.bash
```

---

And when I typed echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH in the terminal ,I got nothing, that's right according to my knowledge even I have to restart the terminal instead of typed soure ~/.bashrc
while if I change the bashrc like this:

---

```
source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash
#export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH:/home/chaoqun/catkin_test/src/ORB_SLAM
source /home/chaoqun/catkin_test/devel/setup.bash
#source /home/chaoqun/active_exploring/devel/setup.bash
```

---

when I echo the ROS path ,I got:

```
/home/chaoqun/catkin_test/src:/home/chaoqun/active_exploring/src:/opt/ros/indigo/share:/opt/ros/indigo/stacks
```

It's really strange why I got the path :/home/chaoqun/active_exploring/src:, it is clearly that I have moved this path in bashrc file. why I still get this ?
But If I write like below:

---

```
source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash
#export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH:/home/chaoqun/catkin_test/src/ORB_SLAM
#source /home/chaoqun/catkin_test/devel/setup.bash
source /home/chaoqun/active_exploring/devel/setup.bash
```

---

Then I can get desired output:

```
/home/chaoqun/active_exploring/src:/opt/ros/indigo/share:/opt/ros/indigo/stacks
```

What's wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/248649/how-many-ros-paths-can-%7E/.bashrc-file-store?-will-the-path-influence-each-other/) by [chaoqunzhuoyue](https://answers.ros.org/users/22062/chaoqunzhuoyue/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2016-11-22

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2016-11-23**:
Please use the preformatted text button (with 1s and 0s) to copy in terminal output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should not manually adapt the `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH`. This will get overwritten every time you source a `setup.bash`. And there, last sourced `setup.bash` wins.

You need to [chain your workspaces](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/workspace_overlaying) correctly.

Let me give you a short example.

You start with `source  /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash`, this gives you:

```
/opt/ros/indigo/share:/opt/ros/indigo/stacks
```

You now create a workspace in `~/catkin_ws`, do a `catkin_make` and `source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash`. This gives you:

```
/home/USER/catkin_ws/src:/opt/ros/indigo/share:/opt/ros/indigo/stacks
```

You will get this every time you `source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash`, no matter which other `setup.bash` you sourced before.

If you now create another workspace, `catkin_ws_overlay` you can do two things:

1. `source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash`, `catkin_make` your new ws `catkin_ws_overlay` and `soruce ~/catkin_ws_overlay/devel/setup.bash`. This will give you

   ```
    /home/USER/catkin_ws_overlay/src:/opt/ros/indigo/share:/opt/ros/indigo/stacks
   ```
2. or  `source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash`, `catkin_make` your new ws `catkin_ws_overlay` and `source ~/catkin_ws_overlay/devel/setup.bash`. This will give you

   ```
    /home/USER/catkin_ws_overlay/src:/home/USER/catkin_ws/src:/opt/ros/indigo/share:/opt/ros/indigo/stacks
   ```

with this, you have "chained" your workspaces such that it first searches `catkin_ws_overaly`, then `catkin_ws` and then `/opt/ros`.

If you want to undo a chaining, simply delete the `build`, `devel` and (potentially) `install` folder, source the setup.bash you want and compile again.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2016-11-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1